# Mysql Order By Optimization with two indexes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, sql-order-by

i have the following table:

Name: Example

```
Fields
Id: Int(10)
Quantity: Int(10)
ProductId: Int(10)
SaleTimestamp: Int(10)

Indexes
ID, Primary, Unique
ProductId, Not Unique
SaleTimestamp, Not Unique
```

How can i optimize the following query?

```
SELECT Quantity FROM Example WHERE Product_id = 'x' ORDER BY SaleTimestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: just replace 'x' in the WHERE clause with an integer

Comment: Why is it slow? It should run fast. Use `explain select ...`to see what is going on

Comment: The table is HUGE it has like more than a MILLION records. When i use EXPLAIN i can see that Mysql is not using SaleTimeStamp index for the ORDER BY clause

Comment: 1 million rows is quite small, see my answer below as to why only one idx is consulted.

Comment: thanks kohjah, i'll try to add the combined index and i'll let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL only uses one index, so for the sake of the query it will only consult the ProductId index, thus the ORDER BY is not able to use an index.

The solution is to add an index to the two columns, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE example ADD INDEX comb( ProductId, SaleTimestamp );
```

Comment: This is good as far as it goes.  Adding `quantity` into the index would make it even more efficient.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - How would adding `quantity` to the index help in a better search (genuinely interested in knowing)?

Comment: Yes. I did not see that. As an added note if you have multiple columns in an index, MySQL is only able to use the index if the columns in the index are consulted on a left to right basis. e.g. if you index columns: a, b, c. You can query using the index: SELECT a, b FROM tbl WHERE a = 1 and b = 2; However, SELECT a, c FROM tbl WHERE a = 1 and c = 2; will not use the index.

Comment: @TJ- . . . The index would then be a covering index for the query.  It is a small optimization, but the engine can satisfy the query using only the index and not have to refer to the original data pages.

Comment: Thank you. Will this optimization (extra column in the index) affect inserts/updates?

Comment: This was indeed the solution to my problem. By adding the combined index between ProductId and SaleTimestamp the query is now being executed really really fast.